# Batch redirect to http instead of https

Tags: 8, redirection, batch-operations

i'm working on a project and all batch callbacks in ***http*** not ***https*** so instead of redirecting to `https://example.com/batch?id=844&op=start` redirect to `http://example.com/batch?id=844&op=start`, and as result **query params** get lost and redirect me after to `https://example.com/batch` which gives me a 403 forbidden page:
[image]

i have checked ***htaccess*** file and also the server i don't have any redirection.
anyone has experienced this, any help ?

**EDIT:**
I have checked the result of `\Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('<front>')->setAbsolute()->toString()` i get the url correct with the right protocol and also i have added:

```
$settings['reverse_proxy'] = TRUE;
$settings['reverse_proxy_addresses'] = array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

to my **settings.php** and again no luck.
**Note:** all redirections in the site works perfectly with https only this one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by the apache server, the **HTTPS** variable wasn't set to **on** so the Drupal in redirection send **Location:** response header with HTTP instead of HTTPS.
So the solution is to set **HTTPS** variable to **on** with:

```
  SetEnv HTTPS on
```

Answer (score 0):

For debugging try to output the result of:

```
\Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('<front>')->setAbsolute()->toString()
```

Is this the wrong protocol, too? Then your browser terminates with a different protocol than the CDN to your web server.

Symfony is able to detect the correct protocol, but you need to configure the CDN (reverse proxy) in settings.php.

Comment: Thanks @4k4 for your answer but it doesn't work, `\Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('<front>')->setAbsolute()->toString()` i have tested this before it gives the right protocol, and also i have added `reverse_proxy` settings but not working either, all redirection in the site works with the https correctly, i will update my question accordingly !